# Как добавить к каждому повторяющемуся элементу списка вводимый элемент?

Tags: python, list

У меня есть список и к каждому элементу `nan` необходимо дублировать этот же самый `nan` рядом с ним.

```
['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Физ', 'Б', 'АлгП', 'Кир', 'ИЯ', 'Ник', 'nan', 'Кин', 'nan']
```

И мне необходимо получить:

```
['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Физ', 'Б', 'АлгП', 'Кир', 'ИЯ', 'Ник', 'nan', 'nan', 'Кин', 'nan', 'nan']
```

Пока что я пришёл лишь к делитанскому решению, вставляя вручную по индексу, но разброс хаотичен и это никак не идёт.

```
if ['nan'][0] in b:
    b.insert(1,'nan')
elif ['nan'][1] in b:
    b.insert(2, 'nan')
```

Comment: Надо сделать перебор по списку, и добавлять новый список. Если словами, то перебрать каждый элемент и скопировать его в список bb, если элемент nan то скопировать этот элемент в список bb два раза

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо не вставлять в имеющийся список (изменять список, по которому идет проход, в большинстве случаев очень плохая идея), а создать новый

```
a = []
for el in b:
    a.append(el)
    if el == "nan":
        a.append("nan")
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько способов.

- Создание нового списка проходом по исходному:

```
lst = ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Физ', 'Б', 'АлгП', 'Кир', 'ИЯ', 'Ник', 'nan', 'Кин', 'nan']

new_lst = []
for x in lst:
    new_lst.append(x)
    if x == 'nan':
        new_lst.append(x)
```

- То же самое, но в одну строчку:

```
new_lst = sum(([x,x] if x == 'nan' else [x] for x in lst), [])
```

- Модификацией исходного списка (проходом по индексам):

```
i = 0
while i < len(lst):
    if lst[i] == 'nan':
        lst.insert(i, 'nan')
        i += 1
    i += 1
```

(если идти по писку с конца, то можно сэкономить одну строчку)

```
i = len(lst) - 1
while i >= 0 :
    if lst[i] == 'nan':
        lst.insert(i, 'nan')
    i -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё такой вот однострочник по приколу нарисовался у меня:

```
lst = ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Физ', 'Б', 'АлгП', 'Кир', 'ИЯ', 'Ник', 'nan', 'Кин', 'nan']
lst2 = [x for x in lst for y in (x, 'nan') if y == x]
```